# Post Javascript to PHP and then retrieve in another javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I m trying to post the value from my `java_post.js` into `php_post.php` and then retrieve in another javascript page, index.html. So far i can post the value into the `php_post.php` and retrieve back into my `java_post.js` as `alert(data)`
 but i cannot retrieve from my index.html

```
Java_post.js

var url_link ="index.html";

//On Click Select Function
$("#table_hot").on('click', 'tbody tr',function(){
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();

$.post('PHP_post/php_post.php',
    {
        postvalue:value
    },
    function(data){
    alert(data);
}
);
});

//Window Pop Out Function
function hotspot_pop(url_link){
newwindow = window.open(url_link, '', "status=yes, 
height=500; width=500; resizeable=no");
}
```

The value is retrieve when the client click the selected table and then post into the `php_post.php`. The `php_post.php` will filter the result and return to `index.html`.

```
$filtered_students = array_filter($ARRAY, function($row) {

$hotspot_value = $_POST['postvalue'];
if($row['name'] == $hotspot_value){
    return true;
}
});

echo $filtered_students;
```

So now i m able to retrieve the value and post into as an alert for my `java_post.js` but the value is no pass into `index.html` and i receive the error for undefined `postvalue`.

```
<html>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
var xmlhttp_user = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url_user = "PHP_post/php_post.php";
xmlhttp_user.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp_user.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp_user.status == 200) { 
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp_user.responseText;    }
}
xmlhttp_user.open("GET", url_user, true);
xmlhttp_user.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So my problem is now, is there any method that allow me to show the value in `index.html` from `php_post.php`. As a reminder the `alert(data)` from `java_post.js` is just a testing purpose to show the value did post and return from `php_post.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is that when you pass the data into your PHP file and receive the data back in your JavaScript, the information only lasts as long as your current request.

To fix this issue, consider using PHP Session variables to store your data, so that you can retrieve it later.

Example:

```
// php_post.php
<?php

start_session();   // initializes session for persistent data

$filtered_students = array_filter($ARRAY, function($row) {

$hotspot_value = $_POST['postvalue'];
     if($row['name'] == $hotspot_value){
         return true;
     }
});

$_SESSION["filtered_students"] = $filtered_students;   // You can now retrieve this in
                                                       // Another PHP file
?>
```

Now in another file (you would switch your HTML file to get from php_get.php):

```
//php_get.php
<?php

start_session();          // Don't forget to start the session

echo $_SESSION['filtered_students'];

?>
```

More information here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can set the desired value into PHP session while at php_post.php.
This way, you can retrieve the session's value on any page you desire.